# Jenkins: Your JAVA_HOME is invalid on OS X

Tags: java, android, macos, jenkins

I am using Jenkins to build an android project on a mac stadium VM.

When I VNC into the VM, I can build the project just fine. Java is installed at `/usr/bin/java`, and my `$PATH` includes `/usr/bin`.

When I run the same commands from the Jenkins job, it fails with

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /var/lib/jenkins/jdk1.8.0_25

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

`/var/lib/jenkins/jdk...` does not exist on the VM. I have also tried updating the build job to include `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin`, but then I get a different error:

```
Error: Failed to run "java -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed.
You can get it from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.
Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: /usr/bin
```

All of the other steps seem to work so I can tell that the code is being downloaded to the workspace and everything else is installed properly, and as I said I can build android on the VM from the command line directly.

What can I do to get Jenkins to build on the VM?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to set the JAVA_HOME on a mac is to use `java_home` after downloading and installing the required JDK from oracle:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
```

If you want Jenkins to use an older version of the JDK ensure use the -v flag:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6`
```

To preview the location just type the java_home command into a Terminal:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home

$ /usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: What is `java_home` ??